# Call Component Constructor in Controller

Tags: php, cakephp, constructor, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.2

I have written a component as below.

```
class GoogleApiComponent extends Component {
    function __construct($approval_prompt) {
        $this->client = new apiClient();
        $this->client->setApprovalPrompt(Configure::read('approvalPrompt'));
    }
}
```

I am calling this in $components variable of AppController.
Then I have written UsersController as below.

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
    public function oauth_call_back() {

    }
}
```

So in oauth_call_back action I wanna create object of GoogleApiComponent and also call the constructor with parameter.
How to do it in CakePHP 2.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the Configure::read() value as a setting property,
or put the constructor logic within the initialize() method of your component.

```
class MyComponent extends Component
{
    private $client;

    public function __construct (ComponentCollection $collection, $settings = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($collection, $settings);
        $this->client = new apiClient();
        $this->client->setApprovalPrompt ($settings['approval']);
    }
}
```

And then write this in your UsersController:

```
public $components = array (
    'My'    => array (
        'approval' => Configure::read('approvalPrompt');
    )
);
```

Or you may write your component as such:

```
class MyComponent extends Component
{
    private $client;

    public function __construct (ComponentCollection $collection, $settings = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($collection, $settings);
        $this->client = new apiClient();
    }

    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->client->setApprovalPrompt (Configure::read('approvalPrompt'));
    }
}
```

I would recommend you to have a look at the Component class, which is within CORE/lib/Controller/Component.php. You'd be surprised of what you'll learn when you read the source code.